# S3 Upload Invoke Lambda Fails - Cross Account Access

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, terraform

I have a lambda that triggers off an S3 bucket upload (it basically converts a PDF to a dataframe and writes it to a different s3 bucket). Both of these belong to AWS account *A*. I would like to allow cross-account s3 access to trigger this lambda from another IAM user from account *B* (`Administrator`), however I am having issues with the `GetObject` operation. Here is how my lambda in account *A* looks:

```
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)
logging.getLogger(__name__).setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id="XXXX",
    aws_secret_access_key="XXXX",
)
s3 = session.resource('s3')
dest_bucket = 'bucket-output'
csv_buffer = StringIO()

def lambda_handler(event,context):
    source_bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    pdf_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    LOGGER.info('Reading {} from {}'.format(pdf_name, source_bucket))
    pdf_obj = s3.Object(source_bucket,pdf_name)
    fs = pdf_obj.get()['Body'].read() #### code is failing here
    df = convert_bytes_to_df(BytesIO(fs)) 
    df.to_csv(csv_buffer,index=False)
    s3.Object(dest_bucket,str(pdf_name.split('.')[0])+".csv").put(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())
    LOGGER.info('Successfully converted {} from {} to {}'.format(pdf_name,source_bucket,dest_bucket))
```

The lambda is failing with this error:

```
ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied
```

I'm aware it's bad practice to have keys in the lambda file but I can't change things at the moment.

The process works fine if I am uploading to the S3 bucket from within an IAM User in account *A* itself, but when I expose the S3 buckets to an IAM user from a separate account, the issues above start happening. This is the S3 bucket policy (terraform) allowing cross-account access to an IAM user from account *B*:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "cross_account_input_access" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.statements_input.id
  policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:user/Administrator"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::capsphere-input"
            ]
        },      
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:user/Administrator"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And here is the policy attached to an IAM user from another AWS account *B* which enables `Administrator` from account *B* to write a pdf to account *A's* s3 bucket programmatically:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I write the file to the bucket from `Administrator` using `aws cli` like this:

```
aws s3 cp filename.pdf s3://bucket-name
```

I can't figure out what else needs to change.

Comment: Could you please clarify which account has the S3 bucket that triggers the event, and which account has the AWS Lambda function, and which account is represented by XXX in the policy. (That is, Account A or Account B in each case.) Also, what do you mean by "the policy attached to account B"? Are you referring to a policy attached to an IAM Role associated with the AWS Lambda function? Please edit the Question to add these details rather than answering via a comment.

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein, I have edited my question based on your queries. Hopefully that is a bit more helpful!

Comment: I am still confused. Policies are not attached to "accounts", so I'm not sure what you mean by "IAM policy attached to external account B". What is that policy attached to? Is it an IAM Role, or a Bucket Policy? Also, I don't understand what you mean by "account A's S3 bucket policy", given that the bucket is in Account B. Please update your question appropriately.

Comment: You are creating a `session` object based on an Access Key and Secret Key. Which account do these credentials belong to? I presume the are from Account B? Are they associated with `XXXXXXXXX:user/Administrator` shown in the policy? What permissions have been assigned to the entity associated with those keys? You are then using those same credentials to write to a destination bucket -- which AWS Account is that destination bucket in?

Comment: My apologies. There is an IAM user called `Administrator` from account B which I am trying to expose access of the S3 buckets from account A. `Administrator` is able to write files to the bucket, but when the lambda triggers, `boto3` runs into an error.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein the credentials belong to account A. The lambda and bucket are all in account A. The idea is to only let an IAM user from account B (`Administrator`) upload files which then trigger the lambda and then they can retrieve the ouput from a separate bucket which has similar read permissions (I have built this bucket and am able to read from it using `Administrator`'s CLI).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah! I have it!

While your Lambda function has permission to access the object, the fact that the object was uploaded using credentials from another AWS Account means that the object is still 'owned' by the other account.

There are two ways to fix this:

#### Turn off ACLs on the receiving bucket

From [Disabling ACLs for all new buckets and enforcing Object Ownership - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ensure-object-ownership.html):

> We recommend that you disable ACLs on your Amazon S3 buckets. You can do this by applying the bucket owner enforced setting for S3 Object Ownership. When you apply this setting, ACLs are disabled and **you automatically own and have full control over all objects in your bucket**.

#### Set ownership when uploading

When uploading the object when using credentials from another, you can specify `ACL=bucket-owner-full-control` (depending on how you perform the upload). This will grant ownership to the AWS Account that owns the receiving bucket.

Comment: Thanks @John Rotenstein, you are an absolute lifesaver. There's no way I would have figured this out by myself!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your situation is:

Account A contains:

- An AWS Lambda function
- A 'source' bucket used to trigger the Lambda function
- A 'destination' bucket used by the Lambda function to store output

You want to allow the `Administrator` IAM User in Account B to upload a file to the source bucket in Account A. This user should be able to retrieve the output from the destination bucket in Account A.

The following would achieve these goals:

- Create an **IAM Role in Account A** and associate it with the Lambda function. Assign permissions to allow `GetObject` from the source bucket and `PutObject` to the destination bucket. There should be **no need** to reference any credentials within the Lambda function itself, since any necessary permissions will be provided via this IAM Role. The policy would be:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject"
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::source-bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject"
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::destination-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

- Add a **Bucket Policy on the source bucket** that permits the `Administrator` user in Account B to `PutObject` into the bucket:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::Account-B:user/Administrator"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::source-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

- Add a **Bucket policy on the destination bucket** that permits the `Administrator` user in Account B to `GetObject` from the bucket and, I presume, list the bucket and delete objects that have been processed:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::Account-B:user/Administrator"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::destination-bucket"
        },      
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::Account-B:user/Administrator"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::destination-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

- Since this is cross-account access, permission must also be granted to the `Administrator` IAM User in Account B to let them access the source and destination buckets. This policy is **not required** if they already have a lot of S3 permissions, such as `s3:*`, since it would work on *any* buckets including buckets in different AWS Accounts. This **policy would go on the IAM User**:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::destination-bucket"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::source-bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::destination-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: thanks. I've actually already set everything up as you described above, and it's still the same- whenever I upload to S3 from `Administrator` from account B the output ist still `AccessDenied` for `GetObject` at `pdf_obj.get()['Body'].read()`. 

When I use the root from account A (where all the infra is hosted) it's totally fine. I'm wondering if it maybe something to do with lambda permissions instead?

Answer (score 0):

What if you add Region information to the session:

```
session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id="XXXX",
    aws_secret_access_key="XXXX",
    region_name="<REGION>"
)
```

Comment: I tried this but it did not work...